# How can I get the size in bytes of a table returned by a SQL query?

Tags: sql-server

How can I get the size in bytes of a table returned by a SQL query in SSMs?

Comment: Returned to what? Some application code, or SSMS, or something else?

Comment: SSMS is what I am using.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you looking for the size of the table, or the size of a row in the table?  The latter is only readily available if all your columns are of fixed size, i.e. nchar and not nvarchar etc.

With var sized columns you can use the maximum length of each column, and sum these, to give you a maximum row size, but this really won't accurately reflect your real row sizes.

```
select sum(max_length)
from sys.columns
where object_id = object_id('MyTable')
```

You might also create a query that returns [DATALENGTH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx) for each column in any particular row to get the total size of only that row.

Comment: ... or you could use `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats` to get much more accurate values for these metrics: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188917.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Remus, that's a new one to me.

Comment: @RemusRusanu - Yes, but can that give me the max size (in bytes) of any column or one row of a table ? If yes, then what would the query be ?

Answer (score 6):

SQL queries don't return tables, they return results. There is no API to determine the size of a result because results have *streaming* semantics, you start reading the result until the end and you cannot know the size upfront. Sending the size upfront would require the server to first get the result, store it somewhere, determine its size (number of rows), and then send the size followed by result. Obviously, this is inefficient and completely undesirable. It is much better to start streaming the result as soon as available w/o having to store it intermediately.

Perhaps you're looking for something else?

The size of a table in the database can always be determined from its number of pages, see [`sys.allocation_units`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189792.aspx). The helper procedure [`sp_spaceused`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188776.aspx) can read and format this information for you.

Comment: I was thinking of estimating the the MAXIMUM size of one row, then getting only the count() of the rows expected. Then, multiply these two numbers to get an estimate of result set. Not sure if this is the right way to go about it. I am stuck in the first step. Can you help me - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22518384/how-do-i-get-the-maximum-memory-consumed-by-all-data-types-in-sql-server Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In SSMS only, you can "include client statistics" from one of the menus which gives *some* information

Otherwise, as per Remus' answer