# How do I get the maximum memory consumed by all data types in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Is it possible to get the memory consumed by a data type in
SQL server ? I want to get the memory in this way -

```
Id, datatypes, base_memory (in bytes), memory_multiplier
1, varchar(x), 2, x
2, int, 2, 1
et cetra.
```

Are there any problems in making such a table ?

I need this table so that I can use it to find out the
maximum memory that can be consumed by one row of ANY 
sql server table.

If there is no SQL query for getting my table, then 
I can create a table manually for it. But, is my table 
the correct way ?

Comment: Have a look at `information_schema.columns`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function DATALENGTH(ColumnName) will help. It returns the length
of data in bytes.

**Query -**

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATALENGTH(COLUMN_NAME) as DataSize
from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'MyTableName'
```

This works, but I don't know if there are any pitfalls in this approach.

**Max size of one row of a table -**

```
SELECT SUM(DataSize) AS MaxRowSize
FROM
(
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATALENGTH(COLUMN_NAME) as DataSize
from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'shop'
) AS SCHEM
```

**Max size of the data set you are interested in -**

```
DECLARE @maxRowSize int
SET @maxRowSize =
(
SELECT SUM(DataSize) AS MaxRowSize
FROM
(
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATALENGTH(COLUMN_NAME) as DataSize
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = 'shop' -- enter table name only, do NOT enter the schema
) AS SCHEM
)
SELECT COUNT(Id) as NumOfRows, 
@maxRowSize as MaxRowBytes, 
COUNT(id) * @maxRowSize as MaxQueryBytes
FROM Shop -- Enter schema name if needed
```

**Shop table schema information -**

```
COLUMN_NAME DataSize
id          4
date        8
sales       10
```

**Sample test with AdventureWorks2008R2 Database -**

Save the results of a query to a text file. See the size of text file. If it is approximately equal to the value returned by my query, then I think we should be
good to go.

```
select * 
from person.Person
where FirstName = 'crystal'
-- Records = 22
```

File: Size = 15.2KB
Query: 6116 bytes

**Result - Does not work for this table !** :(

**Test 2 -**

Table salaries -

```
[id] [int], [name] [varchar](50), [salary] [decimal](18, 2)
```

Table -

```
id  name            salary
1   azamat bagatov  100.50
2   borat           25.00
3   coci buchek     200.50
```

File: Size = 65 bytes
Query: Size = 72 bytes.

**Result - Great success ???**

Answer (score 2):

You can run into problems if you use the type varchar(max), text, image, etc. as they can be a huge amount of memory -- however, the what you probably want to use as a starting point is the view sys.columns, i.e.

```
select top 1000 * from information_schema.columns

select top 1000 * from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'mytable'
```

Look at the results, some interesting columns are character_octet_length and character_maximum_length. But you will see that types life integer will have have a null value -- though these are the values that succumb to the approach you started with.

ADDED

Also note that text / image, etc. are not counted against the 8K limit on a row size, so depending upon why you are computing rou size, you may want to exclude. This does not included some of the additional database overhead sql server uses to store rows.

ADDED

Fixed size elements like integer will be shown as null. You can either get the correct size using the approach you started with, or use the equivalent case statement to get get column size in bytes. I don't recall anywhere sql provides this data exactly in the format you would like.

ADDED Remembered this later

The basic type sizes are defined in sys.types -- don't think I've ever used this, easy to forget.

Comment: These queries do not give me the size of a column. I was hoping that i would at least see int = 4 bytes.

Comment: Added sys.types to answer